# How to compare row values for diff columns for the entire df and obtain the latest record?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df of about 100000 rows, a sample of which is as follows:

```
id  commodity   frequency   ms_id   created modified    measuring_type  tariff  overshoot_delta timestamp   time_series_id  quantity    type
0   12188   1   900 12191   2019-03-25 12:40:00 2019-11-19 05:38:00 29  0   0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12188   50.25   220
1   12858   1   900 12861   2019-04-08 15:13:00 2019-11-19 05:39:00 29  0   0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12858   50.25   220
2   12858   7   900 12861   2019-04-08 15:13:00 2019-11-19 05:39:00 29  0   0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12858   50.25   220
3   12188   1   900 12191   2019-03-25 12:40:00 2019-11-19 05:38:00 29  10  0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12188   50.25   250
4   12188   1   900 12191   2019-03-25 12:41:00 2019-11-19 05:38:00 29  10  0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12188   50.25   250
```

What I would like to do is to check the values in the columns: `commodity`, `measuring_type`, `tariff`, `timestamp`, `type` and see if there are duplicates in any rows. If the values in the above-mentioned columns are exactly the same for any 2 rows, then I want to take the last value (greatest time) from the `created` column. Such a check has to be done for all the rows in the df.

From the above example, the **expected output**:

```
    id  commodity   frequency   ms_id   created modified    measuring_type  tariff  overshoot_delta timestamp   time_series_id  quantity    type
0   12858   1   900 12861   2019-04-08 15:13:00 2019-11-19 05:39:00 29  0   0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12858   50.25   220
1   12858   7   900 12861   2019-04-08 15:13:00 2019-11-19 05:39:00 29  0   0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12858   50.25   220
2   12188   1   900 12191   2019-03-25 12:41:00 2019-11-19 05:38:00 29  10  0   2019-03-16 23:00:00 12188   50.25   250
```

The first 2 rows had same values for the columns `commodity`, `measuring_type`, `tariff`, `timestamp`, `type`, so the time values in the `created` column have to be compared for those 2 rows and the greatest one (`2019-04-08 15:13:00`) has to be selected. Similarly for the last 2 rows.

Since the third row had a different value, it shouldn't be dropped and this must be added to the output.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `sort_values` then `drop_duplicates`

```
df=df.sort_values('created').drop_duplicates(['commodity', 'measuring_type', 'tariff', 'timestamp', 'type'], keep='last')
```